bash Command not executing on Ec2 from Lambda
I'm trying to run certain bash on a Ec2 instance that I create in a Lambda function.
code
const instanceParams = {
      ImageId: "ami-0c101f26f147fa7fd",
      InstanceType: "t2.micro",
      MinCount: 1,
      MaxCount: 1,
      IamInstanceProfile: {
        Arn: iparn
      },
      UserData: Buffer.from(
        `#!/bin/bash
    export NANO_ID="${nanoId}" 
    mkdir test
    echo $NANO_ID > test2.txt
    aws s3 cp ./test2.txt s3://s3storebucketName/test2.txt
    
    aws s3 cp s3://s3storebucketName/Script.js . > test3.txt 2>&1
    aws s3 cp ./test3.txt s3://s3storebucketName/test3.txt
    
    sudo yum install nodejs npm -y > test1.txt 2>&1
    aws s3 cp ./test1.txt s3://s3storebucketName/test1.txt
    
    npm install @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb @aws-sdk/client-s3 > test4.txt 2>&1
    aws s3 cp ./test4.txt s3://s3storebucketName/test4.txt
    
    node Script.js > test5.txt 2>&1
    aws s3 cp ./test5.txt s3://s3storebucketName/test5.txt
    `
      ).toString("base64")
    };
      const data = await ec2.send(new RunInstancesCommand(instanceParams));

above is the code for my instanceParams and how i call my RunInstancesCommand. The bash command that I have given in the UserData. It only runs till before sudo yum install nodejs npm -y > test1.txt 2>&1 meaning there is some issue with the suco yum install command. iparn has the role of AdministratorAccess, and it also has the security group with range of ports and protocols set to all.
I need help in installing nodejs and npm onto my ec2 instance. How should I go about it. what is the easiest way to get the packages installed.
I have to run it in this way. I shouldnt be SSHing into Ec2 via Lambda.
I tried using dnf instead of yum.
